# ASP Checkbox and JS

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I'm trying to check to see if the aspboxes are checked in js. Can I set an ID number to the listItems and check each one by one?

```
           <asp:CheckBoxList ID="CheckBoxList1" runat="server">
         <asp:ListItem Text="Asset Classes" value="Asset Classes"></asp:ListItem>
         <asp:ListItem Text="Asset Types" Value="Asset Types"></asp:ListItem>
         <asp:ListItem Text="Asset Manufactuerer" value="Asset Manufactuerer"></asp:ListItem>
         <asp:ListItem Text="Asset Voltage Class" Value="Asset Voltage Class"></asp:ListItem>
             </asp:CheckBoxList>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No you can't. CheckBoxList's ListItem doesn't have id attribute.

But you can access each item by index.

```
function MyFunction() {
    var CheckBoxList1 = document.getElementById('CheckBoxList1');
    var checkBoxItems = CheckBoxList1.getElementsByTagName("input");

    for (var i = 0; i < checkBoxItems.length; i++) {
        if (checkBoxItems[i].checked) {
            alert(checkBoxItems[i].value);
        }
    }
}
```